# MongoDB select random 5 documents via find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopback, loopback4

I need to find random 5 documents from mongoDB by using find function. I using LoopBack 4 framework. I already try to use sample (it is in comment)

```
 const userParties: IndividualParty[] = (await find(
            this.logger,
            {
                where: {
                    and: [
                        { _id: { nin: ids.map(id => id) } },
                        { gender: { inq: gender } },
                    ],
                },
                //sample: { size: 5 },
                //limit: 5,
            } as Filter<IndividualParty>,
            this.partyRepository,
        )) as IndividualParty[];
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/ zis what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried it with sample, but when I added it into query (you can see it in code), it ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Loopback, but using pure node and node MongoDB driver, here's the shortest example I can come up with:

```
var run = async function() {
  const conn = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {useNewUrlParser: true})
  let agg = [
    {'$match': {'_id': {'$gte': 50}}},
    {'$sample': {'size': 5}}
  ]
  let res = await conn.db('test').collection('test').aggregate(agg).toArray()
  console.log(res)
  await conn.close()
}()
```

In a collection containing `_id` from 0 to 99, this will randomly output 5 documents having `_id` larger than 50. Example output:

```
[ { _id: 60 }, { _id: 77 }, { _id: 84 }, { _id: 96 }, { _id: 63 } ]
```

You would need to make the above example work with Loopback, but the basic idea is there.

**Note:**

You need [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) instead of `find()`.

Have a read through the [$sample documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) and note especially its [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior):

> $sample uses one of two methods to obtain N random documents, depending on the size of the collection, the size of N, and $sample’s position in the pipeline.

The position of `$sample` in the pipeline is important. If you need to select a subset of the collection to do `$sample` on via a `$match` stage (as with the example above), then you will need to ensure that the subset to be sampled is within 16 MB (the limit of MongoDB in-memory sort).